# How can i fill my custom classes properties with an xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, dynamic, properties

My program creates xslt files and stores the information from custom classes there, this is done dynamically with attributes which mark the classes and properties I want to store in the xslt. This was quite easy because i just had to name the attribute like the property and fill the value with the object's toString() method.

Now I want to somehow reload that Information, create the same classes and fill the properties with those values. But how do i do that with e.g. Enums and other complex types if i don't know the type at compile time? Has to be some sort of parse method..

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you dealing with xslt and not XML?

Comment: Because the xslt is not primarily used as a file to store objects. It is a template created by an graphical designer. I want to somehow load that template again so i can configure and change it. 

The reason for this is that i don't need 2 files, the xslt and the save file.

Comment: In this case I think you need to write your custom parser that takes xslt file as an input and parses it creating corresponding instance of a template.

Comment: Do you know how to instantiate classes you don't know until runtime?

(I don't want to hardcode the properties and classes into the code in case some new attributes or elements are added to the xslt  )

Comment: No, it is impossible. But if you could find out their type during parsing then that could help.

Comment: Parsing is done during runtime... !? I'm pretty sure it's not impossible

Comment: Type blabla = Type.GetType("ParseTest.testClass");
Object newTestClass = Activator.CreateInstance(blabla);

It is possible :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to serialize your objects to XML and then desterilize them, and your objects contain interfaces, generic lists or other complex type you can use very useful serialization library http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/sharpserializer.aspx by Pawel Idzikowski.
It is really straight forward and can be very helpful in such cases.